# The arrows of jquery plugin jcarousel-0.3.4 (connected-carousels) doesn't work correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to change the size of the jcarousel to adapt the size of my pictures.
When I change the size, the arrows of the plugin don't work correctly.
The previous arrow don't work correctly.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Connected Carousels - jCarousel Examples</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/jcarousel.connected-carousels.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jcarousel.connected-carousels.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.jcarousel').jcarousel({
            vertical: true
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="connected-carousels">
            <div class="stage" style="position: relative;width: 250px;">
                <div class="carousel carousel-stage" style="position: relative;width: 250px;">
                    <ul>
                        <li style="float: left; width: 250px;"><img src="~/images/books/book1.jpg" width="250" height="390" alt=""></li>
                        <li style="float: left; width: 250px;"><img src="~/images/books/book2.jpg" width="250" height="390" alt=""></li>
                        <li style="float: left; width: 250px;"><img src="~/images/books/book3.jpg" width="250" height="390" alt=""></li>
                        <li style="float: left; width: 250px;"><img src="~/images/books/book4.jpg" width="250" height="390" alt=""></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <a href="#" class="prev prev-stage"><span>&lsaquo;</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="next next-stage"><span>&rsaquo;</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation">
                <a href="#" class="prev prev-navigation">&lsaquo;</a>
                <a href="#" class="next next-navigation">&rsaquo;</a>
                <div class="carousel carousel-navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="~/images/books/book1_thumb.jpg" width="50" height="75" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="~/images/books/book2_thumb.jpg" width="50" height="75" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="~/images/books/book3_thumb.jpg" width="50" height="75" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="~/images/books/book4_thumb.jpg" width="50" height="75" alt=""></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thank, Idan

Comment: Can you place your HTML in JSFiddle alongwith CSS, JS or any working link?

Comment: It doesn't work because you need the image and I think you can't to load them.